# Site no changing after correction css document (using Localhost in Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, localhost

I change some value in css (margin from 20 to 200, for example), and browser dont show any changes - inspected with firebug: margin stay with same value. This situation take place with using Chrome and url(localhost/.../my_html_file_name).

However, if i use custom open html page in browser, any changes are instantly showed.

Also, i tried use localhost in Firefox, and this browser also instantly shows any changes.

P.S.
News: Changed directory name. Problem dissapeared.

Comment: Probably being cached. Clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The browsers use cache, to store pages you frequent, in order to load them faster.
You should clear the cache, because it may happen that the browser loads an older version of the page (the one stored in the cache)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Seems it right way to remove "constant form" of page, Unfortunately i сould not figure out, how i can clear cache for specific localhost folder.